# Cocoon: How to hide a certain column when update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I am working on a new app like SNS. And I stack the case users update the group member with Cocoon. UserGroup model includes current user but current user should not be edited, so I don't want to display current user when the user edit the group member.

I want to skip the column includes current user.

apps/views/group/edit.html.erb

```
  <div class="formItem">
    <h3>Group</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :user_products do |m| %>
      <div id="links">
        <%= render 'maker', f: m %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_association "Add member", f, :user_products, partial: 'maker' %>
  </div>
```

apps/views/groups/_member.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="formField">
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, @cofounder, :id, :username, {}, class: "founderSelect" %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove member", f %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could your update it with better and clearer english?, I still doesn't get what you want to do

Comment: @buncis Sorry for my poor English, I have updated my question. Can you make sense?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? You do not show any classes/models, but your relation is called `user_products`, which would indicate a relation between user and product. Also not sure if that is the parent class of the form, but your comments seem to indicate some kind of project, where one has to select the founders? But a "user" can never remove/edit herself in a project? That seems weird (although very easy to implement). Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @nathanvda Thanks so much! I can achieve eventually. And sorry for my poor explanation...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you want to remove current_user from the cofounder selection group right?

You could do it with `@cofounder.where.not(id: current_user.id)`

Comment: Ow this indeed seems like a very plausible interpretation of the OP's question. Good decyphering :P :P

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can achieve that by your advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%= f.fields_for :user_products, f.object.user_products.where.not(user_id: current_user) do |m| %>
      <div id="links">
        <%= render 'maker', f: m %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

I got it.